# If trapdoor OWF exists then f is a trapdoor OWF, is there such a construction?

Tags: one-way-function, complexity, trapdoor

Is there a known construction of f, such that given that a trapdoor OWF exists then f is a trapdoor OWF, so we can construct inefficient cryptomania, ala Levin's construction for minicrypt in "The Tale of One-way functions"? Is there such a construction, which would yield OWF if we are in minicrypt, but TOWF if we are in cryptomania?